# Make the wearable vibrate from within an android wear app

Tags: wear-os, vibration

I'm writing a simple wearable app to my LG watch that sends vibrations to the watch
on constant intervals and show some mock data.

Although I've looked for an answer, I could't find a way to make the watch vibrate.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Looks as though there may be an answer within the following page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html?

Comment: The question is about the programming task and includes the valuable answer with code snippet.

Answer (score 47):

@Drew, thank you!

If anyone else is interested, here's a code snippet to demonstrate a vibration on your watch:

- Add the following line to your *AndroidManifest.xml*:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  ```
- In your code:

  ```
          Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
          long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 500, 50, 300};
          //-1 - don't repeat
          final int indexInPatternToRepeat = -1;
          vibrator.vibrate(vibrationPattern, indexInPatternToRepeat);
  ```

Comment: you are most certainly welcome!

Comment: so this will make both the phone and watch vibrate ? Lets say i call this code from an android activity from my phone, will the watch also vibrate ?

Comment: @j2emanue No; the vibrate only happens on the device that it is being executed on.

Comment: Do not understand how this could be off topic, this is clearly the programming question with valued 27 score answer.